# Send email from site on asp.net with ubuntu+nginx

Tags: c#, asp.net, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

```
private void SendMessage(Sender sender)
    {
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(_emailAccount.Smtp);
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_emailAccount.Email, _emailAccount.Password);
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_emailAccount.Email);
            mailMessage.To.Add(sender.ForMail);
            mailMessage.Subject = "";
            mailMessage.Body = sender.ToString();
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
```

I have this code to send email from site on asp.net. THis works good on my local pc but doesn't work on ubuntu vps server with nginx as reverse proxy server. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your application can actually talk over the specified port. Check your Nginx and firewall settings to make sure your application is allowed to talk over that port.
[nginx mail proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/) [Linux firewall and iptables](https://opensource.com/article/18/9/linux-iptables-firewalld)